# Why is the where clause of this query evaluating to false?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to understand why the `WHERE` clause of this Redshift query is evaluating to `FALSE` and not returning any results.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT 1 AS id);
```

**Problem:** This query returns no results -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    FALSE as test
  FROM temp)
WHERE test = FALSE;
```

While this query returns the expected one row -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT FALSE) as test
  FROM temp)
WHERE test = FALSE;
```

And alternatively, this works normally -

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 AS (SELECT 1 AS id, FALSE AS test);

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    test
  FROM temp)
WHERE test = FALSE;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce, on my system (postgresql 9.5.4), both queries return 1 row as expected.

Comment: Works for me too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/289fa/2 -- Perhaps something with redshift, not sure.  It uses an older version of `postgresql` and doesn't support all features, although I would still think that would work...

Comment: Thanks for looking into it -- I did specifically say that this was an error I encountered using Redshift, so I'm not surprised it wasn't reproducable with Postgres

Comment: I see the same errors with Redshift.  I even tried to move the select into a CTE and came up with same 0 rows you did. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS (SELECT 1 AS id);
WITH myselect AS (
    SELECT
      id,
      FALSE :: BOOL AS test
    FROM temp)

SELECT *
FROM myselect
WHERE test = FALSE;`